# bootstrap css not getting rendered properly in ngClass

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, font-awesome, ng-class

I've following line of code for displaying a message in modal based on the modal type -

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <span class="fa sb-alert-icon" [ngClass]="{ 'fa-exclamation-circle text-danger': (type == error),'fa-exclamation-triangle text-warning': (type == alert)
     ,'fa-question-circle text-warning': (type == confirm), 'fa-info-circle text-info': (type == info)}">{{message}}</span>
</div>
```

Issue is that, i don't see proper text color for alert message with above conditions and its rendered as white.

[image: Error screenshot]

In browser console I don't see 'text-warning' being rendered. But I do see the place where text color is set to white which is shown below.

[image]

However, if i change above condition to following -

```
<span class="fa sb-alert-icon" [ngClass]="{ 'fa-exclamation-circle text-danger': (type == error),'fa-exclamation-triangle text-warning': (type == alert)
     , 'fa-info-circle text-info': (type == info)}">{{message}}</span>
```

I see 'text-warning' css getting applied properly as shown below.

[image: Working screenshot]
[image: Text Color CSS]

Here CSS overriding doesn't happen.

[image: overriding CSS]

**EDIT-1 :**

.sb-alert-icon has following code -

```
.sb-alert-icon{
  font-size: medium;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Not sure, if this is happening because -

1. using 'text-warning' css consecutively for both 'Alert' & 'Confirm' scenarios.
2. using both Font Awesome and bootstrap together.

Comment: type == error, the `error` is a variable or a string?

Comment: @LonYang - error is an variable and not string.

Comment: I have found the reason of this error. Because the `text-warning` is controled by `type == alert` and `type == confirm`, so it's need `type == alert && type == confirm`, you can try my answer's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class="fa sb-alert-icon" 
  [ngClass]="{
    'fa-exclamation-circle text-danger': type == error,
    'fa-exclamation-triangle': type == alert,
    'fa-info-circle text-info': type == info,
    'fa-question-circle': type == confirm,
    'text-warning': type == alert || type == confirm
   }">
   {{ type }} - {{ message }}
</span>
```